# Passing variable score from one activity to another

Tags: java, android

I'm making a simple quiz app that consist of 10 questions with 10sec countdown timer each questions, which means i have 10 activity for questions. The scoring works while each questions answer correctly multiply by remaining time on CountDownTimer method, so it will be: score = answer * timeLeft; And the total score will be printed on ResultActivity at the end of activity after activity 10.  The problem is i cannot pass my score variable through each activity and when i click next button that intent from activity 10 to ResultActivity, the ResultActivity cannot be open or force close. Here is my code:

TestActivity1

```
package com.finalproject.logicaltest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Timer;

import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.Bind;

import static android.R.id.message;
import static android.R.string.cancel;
import static com.finalproject.logicaltest.R.id.rb1;
import static com.finalproject.logicaltest.R.id.rb2;
import static com.finalproject.logicaltest.R.id.rb3;
import static com.finalproject.logicaltest.R.id.rb4;


public class TestActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Bind(R.id.rb1) RadioButton rB1;
    @Bind(R.id.rb2) RadioButton rB2;
    @Bind(R.id.rb3) RadioButton rB3;
    @Bind(R.id.rb4) RadioButton rB4;
    @Bind(R.id.next) Button bNext;
    @Bind(R.id.timer) TextView cDown;

    public int answer = 0;
    public int score = 0;
    public long timeLeft = 0;
    //The number of milliseconds in the future from
    //the call to start() until the countdown is done
    public long millisInFuture = 11000; //11 seconds
    //The interval along the way to receive onTick(long) callbacks
    long countDownInterval = 1000; //1 second

    public long millisUntilFinished;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test1);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        setTimer();

    }

    public void setTimer() {

        //Initialize a new CountDownTimer instance
       final CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(millisInFuture,countDownInterval){
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
                //do something in every tick
                //Display the remaining seconds to app interface
                //1 second = 1000 milliseconds
                cDown.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                timeLeft = millisUntilFinished / 1000;

            }
            public void onFinish(){
                //Do something when count down finished
                cDown.setText("NEXT!");
                Intent intent = new Intent(TestActivity1.this,TestActivity2.class);
                intent.putExtra("score", score);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                timeLeft = 0;
            }


        }.start();

        bNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                timer.cancel();
                timeLeft = millisUntilFinished;
                Intent intent = new Intent(TestActivity1.this,TestActivity2.class);
                intent.putExtra("score", score);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);

            }

        });

    }

    public void onRadioButtonClicked (View v) {

        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) v).isChecked();

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case rb1:
                if (checked){
                    answer++;
                    break;
                }

            case rb2:
                if (checked){
                    answer = 0;
                    break;
                }

            case rb3:
                if (checked){
                    answer = 0;
                    break;
                }

            case rb4:
                if (checked){
                    answer = 0;
                    break;
                }
        }

        score = ((int)(timeLeft) * Integer.valueOf(answer));

    }




}
```

It pass score with putExtra through TestActivity2 until TestActivity10 like this:

```
package com.finalproject.logicaltest;

/**
 * Created by VICKY on 19-May-17.
 */

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.Bind;

import static com.finalproject.logicaltest.R.id.rb1;
import static com.finalproject.logicaltest.R.id.rb2;
import static com.finalproject.logicaltest.R.id.rb3;
import static com.finalproject.logicaltest.R.id.rb4;
import static com.finalproject.logicaltest.R.id.rb5;

public class TestActivity10 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Bind(rb1) RadioButton rB1;
    @Bind(rb2) RadioButton rB2;
    @Bind(rb3) RadioButton rB3;
    @Bind(rb4) RadioButton rB4;
    @Bind(rb5) RadioButton rB5;
    @Bind(R.id.end) Button bEnd;
    @Bind(R.id.timer) TextView cDown;

    public int answer = 0;
    public int score = 0;
    public long timeLeft = 0;
    //The number of milliseconds in the future from
    //the call to start() until the countdown is done
    public long millisInFuture = 11000; //11 seconds
    //The interval along the way to receive onTick(long) callbacks
    long countDownInterval = 1000; //1 second

    public long millisUntilFinished;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test10);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        score = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("score");

        setTimer();
    }

    public void setTimer() {


        //Initialize a new CountDownTimer instance
        final CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(millisInFuture,countDownInterval){
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
                //do something in every tick
                //Display the remaining seconds to app interface
                //1 second = 1000 milliseconds
                cDown.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                timeLeft = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
            }
            public void onFinish(){
                //Do something when count down finished
                cDown.setText("NEXT!");
                Intent intent = new Intent(TestActivity10.this,ResultActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("score", score);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                timeLeft = 0;
            }
        }.start();


        bEnd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                timer.cancel();
                timeLeft = millisUntilFinished;
                Intent intent = new Intent(TestActivity10.this,ResultActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("score", score);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }

        });
    }

    public void onRadioButtonClicked (View v) {

        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) v).isChecked();

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case rb1:
                if (checked){
                    answer = 0;
                    break;
                }

            case rb2:
                if (checked){
                    answer++;
                    break;
                }

            case rb3:
                if (checked){
                    answer = 0;
                    break;
                }

            case rb4:
                if (checked){
                    answer = 0;
                    break;
                }

            case rb5:
                if (checked){
                    answer = 0;
                    break;
                }
        }

        score += ((int)(timeLeft) * Integer.valueOf(answer));

    }




}
```

And printed total score on ResultActivity:

```
package com.finalproject.logicaltest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static android.R.id.message;


public class ResultActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public int score = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
        score = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("score");
        TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total_score);
        result.setText(score);
    }
}
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You can store the value of the result in shared Preference and fget it in the result screen instead of always passing it.

Comment: Why are you creating activity for each question? You should use Fragment and reuse it as many times as you do have the questions.

Comment: `I'm making a simple quiz app that consist of 10 questions with 10sec countdown timer each questions, which means i have 10 activity for questions` this seems like you're trying to solve the problem in the wrong way. I'd imagine you could just have one generic activity which takes a question and then shows that question, instead of creating a new activity for each question. Right now all your 10 activities are basically copies of each other. Maintaining those will get a lot harder as time goes on.

Comment: What do you mean with not work? The score returns 0 or you get an exception or...?

Comment: Check you **Android Monitor** once for any exception.

Comment: As Sac and nbokmans told you can make a quiz app very more simple and practical. Just make some search. I recommend : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25200551/android-making-quiz-app-with-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Try this code it may help,use according to your logic

**Declarations and Initialization**

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("results", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

**storing your score for using in the other activities**

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("score", score);
            editor.commit();
```

**Retrieving the stored data**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("results", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String lanSettings = prefs.getString("score", null);
```

Comment: Where should i write this code? In onCreate? public class? or  which method ?

Comment: you have to the SharedPreferences before starting the test, onCreate will work fine here

Comment: I just have to add these code or replace it with other wrong code of mine? Which one should i replace? And on the declaration, unlike mine, you didn't declare a global variable like `public int score = 0;` or it will works automatically? Should i let putExtra() written there or replace it with SharedPreferences?

Comment: you should use shared preference instead of sending intents

Comment: editor.putInt("userScore1", zero);

int userScore1 = prefs.getInt("userScore1",0);

editor.putFloat("percantage", 1.2f);

float someFloat = prefs.getFloat("percantage", 0.0f);

Comment: these two examples for int and float in case you want to store percentage

Comment: I see. But are there any way to pass variable only using intents?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Application** class for that , save score value in Application class which can be accessible from any class you want.(as you only need to save score value.) for more info you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208886/using-the-android-application-class-to-persist-data)

Hope it helps..

Comment: While this is a working solution this is generally not recommended. Why should the `Application` class hold this data? It's better to pass it around via intents and extras.

Comment: You only need score value .... for that Application class can work. No doubt intents are the good approach it should work, but Application class can also work here ,check the link i mention.

Comment: My point is that dumping everything in the Application class quickly leads to a tightly coupled system that becomes a monstrosity to do any form of testing/refactoring on.

Answer (score 0):

**IMO** you are setting `score` to your TextView which is incorrect.
Either set it like this:

```
result.setText(String.valueOf(score));
```

or like this:

```
result.setText(" "+score);
```

See if this works.